# Default usb configuration is reset after tablet reboot

Tags: usb-connection-mode, developer-options, usb-tethering

I'm working with Lenovo M10 table model number TB-X5605LC. Android version 9

From Developer options, I am setting up the default USB configuration to be `USB tethering` but after every time the tablet reboots, the default USB configuration is set back to `No data transfer`

How do I prevent this from happening?

[image: This is my setting]

Comment: This is a bug. This should not happen. Only your OEM can fix that. Or, with root access (or adb) you could try to edit the settings. You can also try an automation app to enable USB tethering once USB is plugged in (search this site for solutions) as a workaround.